# Git push publickey permission denied to vm

Tags: ssh, git, sshd

Permission denied when trying to git push origin master from vs code files to my vm ubuntu server, already tried many editions on ssh_config and availablr tutorials, but no one worked, also couldnt find one for a vmware ubuntu server.

Comment: Not quite sure what you’re trying to do here. Is your goal to push code changes from VS Code on your workstation to a server where it will be used?

Comment: Yes, i have my api code on vscode and im trying to git push origin master to a vmware ubuntu server where it will be running